# How to use a class function to initialise redux state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, state

I am trying to create a redux state from a function defined inside a class. I am getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` when I use:

```
var c = new Counter(0)
counter = c.state

let store = createStore(counter)
```

But if I use the `function` `counter(state = 0, action)`, then it works properly.

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

class Counter {
    constructor(s) {
        this.s = s
    }

    state(action) {
        console.log("action" + action)
        switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return this.s + 1;
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return this.s - 1;
        default:
            return this.s
        }
    }
}

function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}

var c = new Counter(0)
counter = c.state

let store = createStore(counter)   // not working

store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))

store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
store.dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT' })
store.dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT' })

export default store
```

How to use class and give a function to initialise the state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When redux calls your reducer, it will pass in two parameters. The first is the redux state, the second is the current action. This is the case no matter what you name your parameters. So since your function looks like this:

```
state(action) {
  console.log("action" + action)
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'INCREMENT':
      return this.s + 1;
  case 'DECREMENT':
      return this.s - 1;
  default:
      return this.s
  }
}
```

...then the redux state will be assigned to the misnamed variable "action". Meanwhile, the action will not be assigned to any parameter. The initial redux state is undefined, thus you're seeing that exception.

Instead, change your function to accept two parameters; the state and the action. In other words, use your working code:

```
function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

This isn't inside a class, but i'm not sure why you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to pass two parameters.

```
function todos(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return state.concat([action.text])
    default:
      return state
  }
}
const store = createStore(todos, ['Use Redux'])
```

Take a look at https://redux.js.org/api/createstore